# Evaluate the improper integral $\int _1^\infty x^{-10/9} \coth(x) \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, improper-integrals

Could someone help me to evaluate this integral  please:
$$\int _1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^{10/9} \tanh(x)} \,\mathrm dx$$

I tried using change variable method in order to change the integral bound.

Comment: I don't downvote because the question is not bad. However in general you have to provide some thought(inside the post, not just title) yourself for every question you post on this site.

Comment: have you proved that this integral exists?

Answer (score 0):

By considering the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the $\sinh$ function:
$$ I=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\coth(x)}{x^{10/9}}\,dx =  2\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{1/9}(\pi^2 n^2+x^2)}=2\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{1/9}dx}{1+\pi^2 n^2x^2}\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ I = 18\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^9\,dx}{1+\pi^2 n^2 x^{18}}\tag{2} $$

where the last integrals can be computed through partial fraction decomposition.
 The eighteenth roots of unity are clearly involved.